# Optimize table in MariaDB for large ibd file

Tags: wordpress, mariadb

We have a WordPress website using MariaDB where a wp_options table keeps growing due to a rogue plugin writing thousands of records to the table. The issue has not been resolved by the plugin maintainer yet and I keep having to remove these 'transient' (temp) records manually via DELETE statement. The problem is the ibd file keeps growing and now 35GB in size. Once this is resolved, I plan to do an OPTIMIZE TABLE on the table to cleanup. Is that the best approach to reclaim all that space? I assume I'll need as much as 40GB free space to do this and how long should the OPTIMIZE TABLE take? Since this table is used quite a bit by WordPress, it seems it will be best to take the website offline while optimizing to avoid locks. I'll looking for the quickest way to resolve.

At least I think these rogue records are the cause of the table growing. Below is a list of the top 10 type of entries in the table:

```
MariaDB [wmnf_www]> SELECT    substr(`wp_options`.`option_name`, 1, 18) AS `option_name`,   count(`wp_options`.`option_value`) AS `cnt` FROM   `wp_options` GROUP BY   substr(`wp_options`.`option_name`, 1, 18) ORDER BY   `cnt` DESC LIMIT 10;
+--------------------+-------+
| option_name        | cnt   |
+--------------------+-------+
| _transient_timeout | 21186 |
| _transient_ee_ssn_ | 12628 |
| _transient_jpp_li_ |   222 |
| _transient_externa |   125 |
| _transient_wc_rela |    63 |
| jpsq_sync-14716436 |    50 |
| wpmf_current_folde |    35 |
| _wc_session_expire |    34 |
| jpsq_sync-14716465 |    29 |
| jpsq_sync-14716417 |    25 |
+--------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.17 sec)
```

The _transient_ee_ssn_ and _transient_timeout_ee_ are the issue and keep growing, the only ones in the set above that has grown since last night and was initially found with 800K records. I keep removing the records as the plugin maintainer said was safe. But is this the cause of the ibd file growing?

---UPDATE---
Oddly enough, the issue is not resolved and transient records keep getting generated by the thousands, but this ibd index file has stopped growing for the moment. After steadily growing over the weekend from 20GB to now 39GB, it has not grown in a couple of hours. Perhaps there's a limit or this file was growing for other reasons?

Comment: This is the 3rd Question recently about wp_options growing tremendously.  One of the plugins is not cleaning up after itself.  Search for the other Q&As.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a better solution to recreate the table using Percona pt-online-schema-change tool. This will recreate the table and move all the data to the new table then drop the old table. This will avoid locking the database for a long time.